# Use multiple sender address in Laravel Email

Tags: laravel, email

How to use different sender address in sending emails in Laravel. What i want is to send some emails from one email id and some mails from second email id but gmail is picking up every time the configuration done in env not from mailable class.

Answer (score 0):

> You can't replace sender with `Google SMTP` service.

> Google rewrites the From and **Reply-To** headers in messages you send via it's `SMTP` service to values which relate to your gmail account.

**GMail** does allow sending via different addresses or alias but this is for sending via the **GMail web app**, see [Here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en)

If you own the domain you are supposedly sending from, use the [Gmail for Domains](https://gsuite.google.com/) , and setup a "*myapp@mydomain.com*" account. 
Or, use **another SMTP provider**